# How to make a UNION but instead of putting at the bottom it will put in left side in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables :
**billing**, 
**debitcredit**, 
**jso**

I want to get the total of all **billing** grouped by customer then add in left side the total of **debitcredit** grouped by customer then add in left side the total of **jso** grouped by customer, I can't do LEFT JOIN because some customer in **billing** is not in **debitcredit**, the same in **jso**

Expected output:

```
subsid   |  debitamt       |  debitcredit        |  amount     |
1        |  200            |  null               |  100        |
2        |  null           |  500                |  300        |
3        |  100            |  200                |  300        |
```

I tried this query but returns blob, and I don't know if it's correct.

```
SELECT
IF(debitamt = "debitamt", 0, debitamt) as debitamt,
IF(debitcredit = "debitcredit", 0, debitcredit) as debitcredit,
IF(amount = "amount", 0, amount) as amount
from (
   SELECT a.subsid, sum(debitamt) as debitamt, "debitcredit", "amount" FROM 
   new.billing a
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b.subsid, "debitamt", sum(debit-credit) as debitcredit, "amount" 
   FROM new.debitcredit b
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.subsid, "debitamt", "debitcredit", sum(amount) as amount FROM 
   new.jso c
) a group by a.subsid
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... corrected your inner select fields and display

```
SELECT
a.subsid,
sum(debitamt) as debitamt,
sum(debitcredit) as debitcredit,
sum(amount) as amount
from (
   SELECT a.subsid, sum(debitamt) as debitamt, 0 as debitcredit,0 as amount   --only need the column defined in first union FROM 
   new.billing a
   group by a.subsid
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b.subsid,0 , sum(debit-credit) ,0
   FROM new.debitcredit b
   group by b.subsid
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.subsid, 0, 0, sum(amount)  FROM 
   new.jso c
   group by c.subsid
) a group by a.subsid
```